# SQL Server or SSIS code for incrementing

Tags: sql-server, ssis, increment

**Input**

```
ID
12345
12346
12346
12387
12568
12387
12387
```

**Output**

```
ID     -  Value
12345  -  1
12346  -  2
12346  -  2
12387  -  3
12568  -  4
12387  -  5
12387  -  5
```

I have an input like shown above and I need an output also shown.

So looking at that, output should be like if the previous value is same as the present value then there shouldn't be a change in value, while if there is change in value, then the value should be incremented.
First value is a default value '1'.

Is it possible to write in SQL server 2008 and above ?
Are there any special functions for this ??

Can we write the same code in SSIS ?
Which one will be easy to accomplish ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is not key constraint use this

```
declare @Id as int, @Rownumber as int = 0
declare @tempTable table (Id int, Rownumber int)

declare tempCur cursor for
select Id from yourtable
OPEN tempCur
FETCH NEXT FROM tempCur
INTO @Id
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
begin

    declare @tempId as int
    select @tempId=id from @tempTable where Rownumber=(select max(Rownumber) from @tempTable)
    if (@tempId = @Id)
        insert into @tempTable select @Id,@Rownumber
    else
    begin
        set @Rownumber = @Rownumber+1
        insert into @tempTable select @Id,@Rownumber
    end

    FETCH NEXT FROM tempCur
    INTO @Id
end
select * from @tempTable
CLOSE tempCur
DEALLOCATE tempCur
```

For your reference :

[image]

Comment: This is perfect...!! 
Will its impact on performance be high ?

Comment: This should be fine unless you are performing `insert`, `update` on `usertables` inside `CURSOR`, and i don't see any reason u'll do so

Comment: I may insert into an user table. That ID column mentioned is just a part of a table which has other columns as well.

Comment: But why u'll do that in cursor, you can do that outside of cursor. right? where we have wrote `select * from @temptable`

Comment: Anyways, you can give it a try, in the mean time i will come up with a query other than this

Comment: Yes.. We can use that temp table keeping things in a single transaction I guess.. Let me try it once.. 
Thanks so much for your time and help..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80289/discussion-between-manoj-soundararajan-and-pravin-deshmukh).

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 08 and above you could do this easily with

```
SELECT Id, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Id)
FROM Table
```

Comment: This orders by Id and then rank it, Note that expected output is not ordered and ranked.